No sound, dual boot, Intel Alder Lake N-95
I have been using Ubuntu since 2008.  Mostly I test on old equipment. At 83 I thought it was time to consolidate and buy a new laptop (my first new computer in 30 years).  I bought a Auusda (intel lake N-95, 32GB, 1TB, Windows 11).  I partitioned the disk 256GB for Windows and the balance for Ubuntu 24.10.  The install went OK. Oops No Sound!  I have tried everything; including all suggestions recommended on Ubuntu forums - nothing!  All that shows is Dummy Output.  During my quest I have been able to get low quality sound from Bluetooth and a USB DAC. Headphones and speakers - dead. I have checked Auusda for updated sound drivers, but all they have is a BIOS update.
FYI - sound card hardware
$ INXI -A
Audio
   Device-1: Intel Alder Lake N PCH High Definition Audio Driver: snd_hda_intel
   Device-2: Texas Instruments PCM2704C stereo audio DAC 
driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid type USB


Can you add more details about the sound hardware? Also, please consider removing the comments about the other computers - they are not relevant to the sound issue. Usually, very recent hardware takes another Ubuntu release to be supported.
